# SQL Joins Query 11

Tags: mysql

I want to join both the tables where contact is either match from Cell or Alt_no
I have tried both these
Didn't work

```
Select *
from #Sales4 a
left join #Feed_Final b
on a.[Contact] in (b.Alt_no,b.Cell)

Select *
from #Sales4 a
left join #Feed_Final b
on a.[Contact] = b.Alt_no or a.[Contact] = b.Cell
```

[image]

Comment: Your Syntax Looks like SQL server

Comment: What means * these Didn't work* ? Any error message or wrong result?

Comment: what's your desired result??

Comment: With respect, "didn't work" can't help us, or you, figure out your problem. It could mean anything. Did you get an empty result set? Did you get an error message? Did your server halt and catch fire? Please [edit] your question to provide more details. And please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My (wild) guess is your second query returns multiple rows per contact and you requirement is to only get one (but which one I wonder) ?

Comment: Yeah you are right it was giving duplicate rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *  FROM Sales4  a 
LEFT JOIN Feed_Final b on a.Contact = b.Cell or a.Contact = b.Alt_no 
GROUP BY b.Contact;
```